# Extracting some SIP headers

Tags: python, python-2.7, sip

I am using this regular expression for SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) URIs to extract the different internal variables.

```
_syntax = re.compile('^(?P<scheme>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.]*):'  # scheme
    + '(?:(?:(?P<user>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\!\~\*\'\(\)&=\+\$,;\?\/\%]+)' # user
    + '(?::(?P<password>[^:@;\?]+))?)@)?' # password
    + '(?:(?:(?P<host>[^;\?:]*)(?::(?P<port>[\d]+))?))'  # host, port
    + '(?:;(?P<params>[^\?]*))?' # parameters
    + '(?:\?(?P<headers>.*))?$') # headers
m = URI._syntax.match(value)
    if m: 
        self.scheme, self.user, self.password, self.host, self.port, params, headers = m.groups()
```

and i want to extract specific header like the header via,branch,contact,callID or Cseq.
The general form of a sip message is:

```
OPTIONS sip:172.16.18.35:5060 SIP/2.0
Content-Length: 0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.16.18.90:5060
From: "fake" <sip:fake@172.16.18.90>
Supported: replaces, timer
User-Agent: SIPPing
To: <sip:172.16.18.35:5060>
Contact: <sip:fake@172.16.18.90:5060>
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Call-ID: fake-id@172.16.18.90
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 003024 +0000
Max-Forwards: 70
```

Comment: "Code formatting" is, for future note, completely appropriate for multi-line literal content such as a SIP message (optionally with a comment turning off syntax highlighting, of the form `<!-- language: lang-none -->`, preceding). If you'd formatted the message that way, contents such as the `To` and `Contact` addresses (formatted in a way that looks like HTML tags) wouldn't be missing.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking advantage of the intentional similarities between SIP header format and RFC822.

```
from email.parser import Parser
msg = Parser().parsestr(m.group('headers'))
```

...thereafter:

```
>>> msg.keys()
['Content-Length', 'Via', 'From', 'Supported', 'User-Agent', 'To', 'Contact', 'CSeq', 'Allow', 'Call-ID', 'Date', 'Max-Forwards']
>>> msg['To']
'<sip:172.16.18.35:5060>'
>>> msg['Date']
'Thu, 25 Apr 2013 003024 +0000'
```

...etc. See the documentation for [the Python standard-library `email` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.html) for more details.